# Add CSS Class to Django-Autocomplete-Light ModelSelect2 Container/Selection

Tags: python, css, django, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light

I have a model form that is made up largely of `django-autocomplete-light` `ModelSelect2` boxes:

```
class AlertForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Alert
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'entity': ModelSelect2(url='eda', attrs={'data-minimum-input-length': 2}),
            'logic': ModelSelect2(url='logic', attrs{'class':'hello'})
        }
```

The CSS class `hello` which I am attempting to add to the `logic` select box does not appear when the page is rendered. How do I add a CSS class to a `dal` select box?

**Edit:** Even if this did add a class to the select box, the class actually needs to be added to the select *container*. How would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS selector
**.class-name + span**
so u select span container and apply whatever CSS u want.